# Characterization of Gaussian numbers, proof explanation

Tags: proof-explanation, algebraic-number-theory, gaussian-integers

> $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ consists of exactly the numbers of the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(i)|\mathbb{Q}$, which fulfull the normed equation $x^2+ax+b=0$ with coefficients $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$.
>
> Proof: An element $\alpha=c+id\in\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is root of the polynomial $x^2+ax+b\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ with $a=-2c, b=c^2+d^2$.
>
> If $c$ and $d$ are integers, then $a$ and $b$ are. If in reverse $a$ and $b$ are integers, so are $2c$ and $2d$. Because $(2c)^2+(2d)^2=4b\equiv 0\mod 4$ hence $(2c)^2\equiv (2d)^2\equiv 0\mod 4$, since quadratic integers are either $\equiv 0$ or $\equiv 1$. So $c$ and $d$ are integers.

This is taken from the german edition of "Algebraic Number Theory" by Jürgen Neukirch.
I hope I translated sufficiently.

In my opinion this proof is pretty short, so I do not understand it in detail. I was not able to fix everything, so I would like to ask for your advice.

Also I am actually a little bit confused. I understand and read the proof that there is an equivalence to be shown.

So:

1. The elements of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ are the elements of $\mathbb{Q}(i)|\mathbb{Q}$ which solve the equation $x^2+ax+b=0$ with integer coefficients.
2. If an element of $\mathbb{Q}(i)|\mathbb{Q}$ solves $x^2+ax+b=0$ then this element is in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

The conclusion "An element $\alpha=c+id\in\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is root of the polynomial $x^2+ax+b\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ with $a=-2c, b=c^2+d^2$." needs more elobaration in my opinion.

It is clear what to do:

$(c+id)^2+a(c+id)+b=0 \Leftrightarrow\quad$ $c^2-d^2+ac+b=0$ and $ad+2cd=0$, when we compare imaginary part and real part.

I see that the result in the proof comes from the case where $d\neq 0$.
So I wanted to know, why $d=0$ does not occur.

We get $c^2+ac+b=0$. With the quadratic formula $c_{1,2}=-\frac{a}{2}\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2-b}$.

I tried to show that the RHS can not be an element of $\mathbb{Q}$, but I was not able too.

Can you provide some more elaboration to this proof?
Also what seems to be the other implication "$\Leftarrow$" puzzles me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see why $d = 0$ must be excluded. In this case, you obtain the integers as a subring of $\mathbb Z[i].$

Comment: @Carlo But how do you get $a=-2c$ and $b=c^2+d^2$ when $d=0$?

Comment: Given that $d = 0,$ we have that $c^2 + ac + b = 0.$ Observe that $a = -2c$ and $b = c^2 = c^2 + d^2$ is a solution to this equation.

Comment: @Carlo Yes, but why is this the only solution?

Comment: I would still appreciate an answer to this. :) Thanks.